# How to fix displaying JSON Object received from stomp client into the view

Tags: angular, spring, websocket, stomp

i can't display the received JSON message from stomp client 
i have tried to parse into JSON Object but not working

```
 _this.stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
      _this.stompClient.subscribe(_this.topic, res => {
   this.receivedMessage=JSON.parse(res.body);
  console.log(this.receivedMessage); });
 }, this.errorCallBack);
```

Comment: ChatroomComponent.html:55 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'recentMessage' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (ChatroomComponent.html:55)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:22503)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:21878)
    at callViewAction (core.js:22114)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:22056)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:21879)
    at callViewAction (core.js:22114)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:22056)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:21879)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:22767)

Comment: Do you have try something like this JSON.stringify(res, null, 2); ?

Comment: stringify is used to convert json to string cuz websocket accept only string format and then send it to java server

Comment: i must use JSON.parse()  but res.body is json by default , i am using this local attribute to save the res.body and then to display it in view side but i get this Error